# Summary of Flight Destinations & Frequency from a specified city

Tags: online-resources, tips-and-tricks, flight-search-engines

I'm often interested in figuring out what destinations I can get to non-stop with a particular airline from a particular origin city; this is helpful in getting a sense for what airline might have more flexibility for same day changes or in figuring out what cities I could go to with miles from a particular airline / alliance.

For example, for JetBlue from LAX, we have the following direct flights

```
HNL (Honolulu), 3x daily
FLL (Fort Lauderdale), 2x daily
JFK (New York), 2x daily
BOS (Boston), 1x daily
BUF (Buffalo), 1x daily
```

Options which aren't great:

- Airline route maps (e.g. [jetBlue](https://www.jetblue.com/route-map/)) typically show all the destinations available (making it hard to distinguish between nonstop routes and connecting routes), and do not provide frequency information.
- Airport sites (e.g. [LAX](https://www.flylax.com/en/flight-search-list?type=dep)) typically allow you to filter by airline, but list the flights individually.

Here's what I typically do:

- Searching Google for a particular city provides an overview of what nonstop flights are available:

[image]

- Searching Google for a pair of cities I am interested in lists the specific flights, and when they run:

[image]

Unfortunately, this process is still relatively manual; are there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most airlines have interactive route maps that do exactly what you're looking for.

In your very question you've called out the [JetBlue route map tool](https://www.jetblue.com/route-map/) claiming it doesn't do this - but it does.  Simply select the "Non-stop" option, and then select an airport and it will show you only direct flights from that airport.

These generally will not show frequency, which isn't surprising given that frequency changes day-to-day and month-to-month.  Once you know that a flight exists, simply searching on the same website for that flight on a specific day will show the number of flights available on that day.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that option on the JetBlue website out --- I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: I'll leave the question open for a few more days in case other users have other ideas. The interface on many of these sites makes it harder to extract information in tabular information --- which is something I am interested in (but didn't specify in the original question).

Answer (score 1):

If a particular airport has a tabular listing of all flights, usually you can copy the entire table and paste it into a spreadsheet.  Then you can filter or sort by any column easily.

This works on almost any HTML table in Safari.  I think I've also done it with other browsers.

If you get unwanted formatting, you can paste special or first paste into a plain text file.